# How to change column types when using a scanner in pyarrow.dataset to convert a large csv file to parquet?

Tags: python, csv, dataset, pyarrow

I'm trying to convert a .csv file to parquet format.  It's too big to fit in memory, so I'm using pyarrow.dataset().  I have this working fine when using a scanner, as in:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow as pa
source = "foo.csv"
dest = "Data/parquet"

dt = ds.dataset(source, format="csv")
part = ds.partitioning(pa.schema([("date", pa.date32())]), flavor="hive")
ds.write_dataset(scanner, dest, format="parquet", partitioning=part)
```

My problem is that the .csv file has a column "time", with values like:

> 2022-01-03 14:30:00.000652 UTC

When using the above, the column ends up being a string.  I can work around that by converting it using panda's to_datetime() when I read it in, but it's a lot of records, so that takes an excessive amount of time whenever I read the data.  So, I'd like that column to be stored as a timestamp.

I tried to pass a schema to `ds.write_dataset()`, but it gave back an error:

> ValueError: Cannot specify a schema when writing a Scanner

I tried to pass a schema to `ds.dataset()`, with the type for that column being `pa.timestamp("ns")`, `pa.date64()`, `pa.date32()`, and `pa.time64("ns")`, but I get a CSV conversion error for the values in that column.

How do I get `pyarrow.dataset` to properly parse those values and save them as timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

`ds.dataset` accepts a schema as an optional input.

```py
In []: schema = pa.schema({"date": pa.date32(), "time": pa.time32("s")})

In []: dt = ds.dataset(source, format='csv', schema=schema)

In []: dt.schema
Out[]: 
date: date32[day]
time: time32[s]
```

Comment: I should have mentioned the format of the data in that column.  It has values like "2022-01-03 14:30:00.000652 UTC".  I tried the above with time64("ns"), date32(), date64(), and timestamp("ns").  In all cases I get a conversion error for the values in that column.  I'll add the details in the original question.

Comment: There is also a compute function `pyarrow.compute.strptime`, which can be used with fields in projected columns. However, it's known issue it doesn't support fractional seconds: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/20146.